# On Bertrand and Mannheim curves.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have been studying Bertrand and Mannheim curve pairs. With regards to Mannheim curve, it is defined as any curve $ \gamma(t) $ so that $ \exists\, \gamma_0(t) $, a curve distinct from $ \gamma(t)$ and a correspondence between the two curves so that the normal line at $ \gamma(t) $ coincides with the bi-normal line at corresponding point $\gamma_0(t) $in any parameter $t$, $\gamma_0(t) $ being called the Mannheim mate of $\gamma$.

Can anyone please give me some examples to visualise these kinds of curves? Further I wish to prove that

$$\gamma(t)=\gamma_0(t)+c\hat b_0(t) $$

$\hat b_0(t)$ being the unit bi-normal to $ \gamma_0(t)$.

I had proved something similar for Bertrand curves where two normal lines coincide. However I am faltering here.

Answer (score 1):

Since I finally found the answer, I thought I might add it here as it might benefit someone else. The second question is answered using just the idea of addition of position vectors.

As for the first question, I found that Helices are one example of Mannheim curves. I would be much grateful if anyone could provide some more exotic examples though.